# Analytic Function on a Half Plane Bounded at the Boundary Must Be Bounded

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, mobius-transformation

I want to verify an argument that supposedly shows that any analytic function in, let's say, the right half plane that is bounded in the boundary must be itself bounded by the same bound. That is if we take $H^+=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\; |\; \text{Re}(z)\geq 0\}$ and a continuous function $f:H^+\to\mathbb{C}$ that is analytic in the interior and such that there is some $M\geq 0$ such that $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all $z\in\partial H^+$ then it must be that this inequality is true for all $z\in H^+$. The argument is as follows: If we consider the the function $f\left(\frac{z+1}{1-z}\right)$ this is an analytic function on the the unit disk  so by the maximum modulus principle, this function must be bounded by the points in the unit circle which are sent to the imaginary axis by the mobius transformation even the point at infinity. From this it seems to obviously follow what I claim. However this sounds too good to be true and so I would like to ask for someone to verify or counter the argument.

Comment: How about $f(z)=e^z$? It is bounded on $\text{Re}(z)=0$.

Comment: @Yuval Yeah the argument is clearly wrong, but for some reason I'm having trouble seeing why.

Comment: To get boundedness on the unit disk you need $f\circ\mu$ to be continuous on its closure, where $\mu$ is your Mobius transformation. Your conditions do not guarantee that it will be at $z=1$. Just being holomorphic inside the disk and bounded on the boundary is not enough. It can have essential singularity on the boundary and stay bounded along the boundary directions, but not when approaching it from the inside. Maximum modulus principle does not preclude it from growing to $\infty$ there. This is what happens with $exp\circ\mu$.

Comment: $\sin (iz)$ is another counter-example. However, if you assume that $|f|$ is bounded in the right half plane then we can show that it is bounded by $M$, the supremum on the boundary.

Comment: another way to think of this is within Hardy Space theory -for example on the unit disc (where the theory is simpler in many ways than in a half plane where it is similar but has the added complication of the point at infinity),  if you know that $f$ is in some Hardy space and its boundary limit (which then exists ae) is bounded, then $f$ is bounded; $e^{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}$ is the basic counterxample for a function that is just bounded on the circle, but unbounded in the disc